# Use a file as input in a R function

Tags: r

I am totally new to R and I'm trying to run a function from a specific package : getId.

It works like this :

data<-getId(c('Pestivirus A','Bos taurus','Homo'),taxaNames)

However I have a lot of different data like 'Pestivirus A'. I have all of the inputs in a tsv files like this :

```
Pestivirus A
Bos taurus
...
```

Is there a clean easy way to put all these 7000 inputs ?

So far I converted my results in a .txt file like this :

```
'Pestivirus A','Bos taurus','Homo'...
```

And I have tried  to import this file like this :

```
> species <- read.csv("C:/Users/vdoinel/Desktop/5_species.txt")
```

But  I get an error " Error in file(file, "rt") : impossible d'ouvrir la connexion" and "No such file or directory". But anyway even if it has worked I don't know what to do after.

Comment: first it seems your file is not on path. Could you manually check  whether the file is present on the given path? probably the path is incorrect. Try running `list.files('C:/Users/vdoinel/Desktop/', pattern = '5_species')` is your fle listed? if not, it shows that either the pathe is incorrect or the file simply does not exist

Comment: Not sure wehre to start helping you. Have you read an R tutorial or some gentle introduction to R? I have given some hints how to achieve your goal in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

- `read.csv` returns a "data.frame", which is a two dimensional data structure with rows and cols. Let us call this data.frme "x". Make sure to read the file with `header=FALSE`, because you do not have colnames.
- all your items are in one row (the first one), so you can read them with `items <- x[1,]`
- you can loop over your items with `for (item in items) {...}`

The details should be looked up in your preferred R reference book/site.

Comment: Not sure how for loop can help me, cause I need to have all of the item in the function. But I guess I can split and concatenante the results after. I have actually copy pasted my whole .txt file in the console in my function (7000 item) but when I run I get a + instead of a > in the console and when Icheck data there is nothing (I expect a line of 7000 associated values) maybie I have to split my .txt

Comment: `read.csv` does the splitting for you and returns the data in a dataframe. You do not need to do low level file io!

Comment: Ok ! So I have tried in console : for (item in items) {data<-getId(c(item),taxaNames) } but it doesn't work. Sorry I'm a beginner in info and I'm learning the hard way

Comment: I admit I am a bit lost

Comment: @Vincent Please read a tutorial about dataframes, e.g. http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame (read *all* section, including the last one: "data import").

Answer (score 0):

While there is nothing wrong with @cdalitz answer, I personally prefer the [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/), which allows you to do the same things in a (imho) nicer way.

In your case:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# list all .txt files, the $ signals end of text
files <- list.files(pattern = ".txt$")

# map the files to the function read_tsv (reads in the data); 
# assign the filenames as names to the list
data <- map(files, read_tsv) %>% set_names(files)

# data is now a list containing the data of the files;
# each slot holds data from one file

# combine the list to a single dataset/data.frame with a new variable called "file" containing the file name
data_all <- bind_rows(data, .id = "file")
```

Comment: Generally, I prefer builtin solutions. Concerning *tidyverse*, this might be a bit too much for a beginner, and I would recommend him/her to learn the "standard" way first, before moving on to tricky stuff.

Comment: True, sometimes light dependencies are really the way to go. I have taught tidyverse immediately after basic R syntax and mostly people felt comfortable as it has a really nice and mostly consistent API with great performance and usability. I think it really depends on the people after all. Meaning to say, learning R via the tidyverse is a valid option for some.